# connect HTML to Appjs React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How to connect my index.html into App.js (React)?

```html
<div class="content">
  <form action="v2/v2.html" class="form">
    <label for="user">Nama</label>
    <input type="text" name="user" id="user" />
    <button type="button" id="load-app">Load App</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script src="v3-website/src/App.js"></script>
```

so when I click the button I want it to direct into App.js
can someone tell me how to do that?

I use `anchor` tag it don't work

Comment: Assuming you are trying to redirect to a react app on button submit, you need to first build and deploy your react app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Javascript `CustomEvent` to communicate between React Virtual DOM and javascript real dom.

referent the below snippet.

```js
const MyEvent = {
  on(event: string, callback: (e: any) => void) {
    document.addEventListener(event, (e: any) => {
      const data = (e as {
        detail: any
      }).detail
      callback(data)
    })
  },
  dispatch(event: string, data ? : any) {
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(event, {
      detail: data
    }))
  },
  remove(event: string, callback ? : (e: any) => void) {
    if (callback) {
      document.removeEventListener(event, callback)
    }
  },
}

export default MyEvent
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to redirect to a react app on button submit, do the following  steps:

- Build your react app.
- Deploy your react app.
- Find deploy path of your react app and use that path on your form `action` attribute.
- For form submission, you should use the `method="GET"`.

**Details**

- First you need to build your react app. Run command:

> npm run build

- Once your react app is built, there will be an index.html file generated inside a `build` directory.

> build/index.html

- After build step, you need to deploy your react app to a web server. For serving locally, you can use `npm serve'

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve

- Find the deploy path of your react app and use that path on form `action` attribute.